# How to deactivate the Color Ramp in QGIS graduated vector styling?

Tags: qgis, vector, style

I want to display points with different size and I DO NOT want to have a color ramp.
Do you know how I can do that?[image: the settings menu: I cannot deactivate the color ramp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the attribute classification and select 'Change Color'.

You can also change the size through the same context menu.

[image]

In the screenshot below, I've changed all colors to yellow and implemented a size gradient.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

QGIS 2.10 and above will have the ability to graduated by size alone built in.

Comment: Do you really mean 2.10? 
I have the version 2.8 Wien and it doesn't work ...
Just with the little workaround ...

Comment: Yes, the upcoming 2.10 release has this. It's available now if you try a development snapshot release too.