# Graduated style- Qgis 2.12

Tags: point, qgis-2.12, color-ramp

I try to represent point layer with different size and i want to have a color ramp also:

[image]

The problem is that when i  choose the color method, the size method disappear:

[image]

I can change the color manually, but i seek for automatic way.

I also have red this [How to deactivate the Color Ramp in QGIS graduated vector styling?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148374/how-to-deactivate-the-color-ramp-in-qgis-graduated-vector-styling) and didn't got my wanted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **Rule-based** style.

[image]

First you can generate breaks in Graduated tab, then in Rule-based classes will appear and you will be able to set sizes of markers.

Comment: how can i  set sizes of markers?

Comment: Just click on them.

Comment: but i don't want to change the size by myself- i want it to be automatic